# Special folders in Android

Tags: c#, android, special-folders

Can anyone tell what is the C# equivalent of

```
Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
```

in Android?

I use monodevelop for android development.

Comment: If the apps I have on my phone say anything, it's that nobody tries to use any sort of "standard location" to store anything...my personal favorite is the one dropping all sorts of crap right at the top level of my sdcard...

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't need it since creating/reading files etc without pathing them uses this directory:

```
public String getApplicationDataDirectory() throws Exception 
{
    return getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).applicationInfo.dataDir;
}
```